# Too slow first run TorchScript model and its implementation in Flask

Tags: python, flask, pytorch, torchscript

I'm trying to deploy torchscripted model in Python and Flask. As I realized (at least as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19106#issuecomment-481772478) ) that scripted models need to be "warmed up" before using, so first run of such models takes much longer than subsequent ones. My question is: is there any way to load torchscripted models in Flask route and predict without loss of "worm-up" time? Can I store somewhere "warm-uped" model to avoid warming-up in every request?
I wrote simple code that reproduce the "warm-up" pass:

```
    import torchvision, torch, time
    model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
    model = torch.jit.script(model)
    model.eval()
    x = [torch.randn((3,224,224))]
    for i in range(3):
      start = time.time()
      model(x)
      print(‘Time elapsed: {}’.format(time.time()-start))
```

**Output:**

```
Time elapsed: 38.29<br>
Time elapsed: 6.65<br>
Time elapsed: 6.65<br>
```

And Flask code:

```
    import torch, torchvision, os, time
    from flask import  Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def test_scripted_model(path='/tmp/scripted_model.pth'):
        if os.path.exists(path):
            model = torch.jit.load(path, map_location='cpu')
        else:
            model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
            model = torch.jit.script(model)
            torch.jit.save(model, path)
        model.eval()
        x = [torch.randn((3, 224, 224))]
        out = ''
        for i in range(3):
            start = time.time()
            model(x)
            out += 'Run {} time: {};\t'.format(i+1, round((time.time() - start), 2))
        return out
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)
```

**Output:**

```
Run 1 time: 46.01; Run 2 time: 8.76; Run 3 time: 8.55;
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 & Windows10
Python version: 3.6.9
Flask: 1.1.1
Torch: 1.4.0
Torchvision: 0.5.0

**Update:**

Solved "warm-up" problem as:

```
with torch.jit.optimized_execution(False):
    model(x)
```

**Update2:**
Solved Flask problem (as mentioned below) with creating global python model object before server starts and warming up it there. Then in each request the model is ready to use.

```
    model = torch.jit.load(path, map_location='cpu').eval()
    model(x)
    app = Flask(__name__)
```

and then in @app.route:

```
@app.route('/')
def test_scripted_model():
    global model
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Once "warmed up", do the models "cool down"? How soon? Do you have enough RAM, just in case?

Comment: After "warming-up" model works well, but not in flask app, cause each request new app_context is creating and new model is loading, so it has to be "warmed-up" again. I don't know how I can store warmed model between requests to avoid time loss each time. The code above can demonstrate it, - refresh the page of flask app and first model run will be again the slowest. And yes, I have enough memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I store somewhere "warm-uped" model to avoid warming-up in every request?

Yes, just instantiate your model outside of the `test_scripted_model` function and refer to it from within the function.

Comment: Sorry, not quite understand what you mean. You suggest to add a function with loading scripted model and from route function call this function? It changes nothing for me. Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: @tuuka `@app.route('/')` means that the function is only executed when a request is made. So perform your "warm up" work outside the function so that it happens when the server is started, and then it's kept in memory.